# Is it possible to implement a broadcastreceiver with BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

Just as topic. We are a few developers trying to implement a broadcastreceiver using Bluetooth Low Energy, but we can't find anything at all.

We know it is possible to register a receiver using `startDiscovery()`, but that doesn't seem to work with BLE.

Is it something we have missed or are there any workarounds for this problem? We want to make a toast on a hidden application as soon as there are devices available to connect to.

We don't want to use startLeScan with a callback, but want to use the system broadcasts on Discovery.

Also, a service is not an option since we are making an API, and we want it to be easy to implement our code.

This is what we tried:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      android.util.Log.i("Yeah", intent.toURI());
   }
};

getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(br, 
new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Comment: Please have a look http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: I have been there, is there something you think I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery() is for discovering Bluetooth (not low energy) devices.

android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() is for discovering Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices.

If you want to receive bluetooth device discovery events from a BroadcastReceiver then you'll have to use Context.sendBroadcast within a android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback method. Implementing LeScanCallback is currently the only way to receive BLE device discovery events in the Java Android API.